# SQL query update

Tags: mysql, sql, ipb

Any assistance is appreciated. We need to update  ibf_posts.author_id.  I have tried this but it doesn't seem to work.  No errors but the query hasn't finished after hours of running. 2.9g dbase. ibf_posts is 1.9g

```
UPDATE ibf_posts SET author_id = (SELECT member_id FROM ibf_members 
                 WHERE ibf_members.members_display_name = ibf_posts.author_name)
```

Tables: ibf_posts, ibf_members

ibf_posts.author_name = ibf_members.members_display_name

ibf_posts.author_id = ibf_members.member_id

```
[slinky = slinky]
[4814 = 4814]
```

but we have:

```
[slinky = slinky]
[0 = 4814]
```

Comment: I don't understand what most of this means, but if your query is running for hours then you should check that the table isn't locked by something/someone else.

Comment: Do you know your members_display_name and author_name are unique?

Comment: ... and what are your indexes? Can you please post your table creation scripts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it like this:

```
UPDATE ibf_posts, ibf_members
SET ibf_posts.author_id = ibf_members.member_id
WHERE ibf_members.members_display_name = ibf_posts.author_name;
```

Comment: This work great.  Not at first but perfect after I indexed the columns.  Thank you.